# How to model a JobService as a sticky service?

Tags: android, android-service, android-jobscheduler, google-text-to-speech

As per the target requirements to Android O, I had to re-implement a service to initialize text-to-speech object as a *job-scheduled service*.

**My original service is implemented as follows - TTSService.java**

*Code for TTSService class:*

```
package services;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;

public class TTSService extends Service {

private static TextToSpeech voice =null;

public static TextToSpeech getVoice() {
return voice;
}

@Nullable
@Override

public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
// not supporting binding
return null;
}

public TTSService() {
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

try{

        voice = new TextToSpeech(TTSService.this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(final int status) {

            }
        });
}
catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
 }


  return Service.START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
 clearTtsEngine();
 super.onDestroy();

}

public static void clearTtsEngine()
{
if(voice!=null)
{
    voice.stop();
    voice.shutdown();
    voice = null;
  }
 }
}
```

**To re-implement this service as a job-scheduled service, I used the following methods in my PhoneUtils class,**

```
public static void scheduleTTSJob(Context context) {

if(isTTSJobServiceOn(context))
{
    return;
}

if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

    ComponentName serviceComponent = new ComponentName(context, TTSJobScheduledService.class);
    JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo.Builder(JOB_ID, serviceComponent);

    builder.setMinimumLatency(1 * 1000); // wait at least
    builder.setOverrideDeadline(3 * 1000); // maximum delay
    JobScheduler jobScheduler = context.getSystemService(JobScheduler.class);
    jobScheduler.schedule(builder.build());
}
}

public static boolean isTTSJobServiceOn( Context context ) {

boolean hasBeenScheduled = false;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

    JobScheduler scheduler = (JobScheduler) context.getSystemService( Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE );

    for ( JobInfo jobInfo : scheduler.getAllPendingJobs() ) {
        if ( jobInfo.getId() == JOB_ID ) {
            hasBeenScheduled = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}

return hasBeenScheduled;
}

public static void stopTTSJob(Context context)
{
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    JobScheduler scheduler = (JobScheduler) context.getSystemService( Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE );

    for ( JobInfo jobInfo : scheduler.getAllPendingJobs() ) {
        if ( jobInfo.getId() == JOB_ID ) {

            scheduler.cancel(JOB_ID);
            break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

**and the service is re-implemented as follows:**
*TTSJobScheduledService class*

```
package services;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.job.JobParameters;
import android.app.job.JobService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;

import com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics;

import utilities.PhoneUtils;

/**
* Created by Admin on 30-Sep-18.
*/

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public class TTSJobScheduledService extends JobService {

private static TextToSpeech voice =null;

public static TextToSpeech getVoice() {
    return voice;
}

@Override
public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
    startTTSEngine();
    PhoneUtils.scheduleTTSJob(getApplicationContext()); // reschedule the job
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
    clearTtsEngine();
    return true;
}

private void startTTSEngine()
{
    try{
        voice = new TextToSpeech(TTSJobScheduledService.this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(final int status) {

            }
        });
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Crashlytics.log("TTS initialization issue");
        Crashlytics.logException(e);
    }
}

private static void clearTtsEngine()
{
    if(voice!=null)
    {
        voice.stop();
        try {
            voice.shutdown();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            Crashlytics.log("ClearTTSEngine shutdown issue");
            Crashlytics.logException(e);
        }
        voice = null;
    }
 }
}
```

It seemed to work well on devices with Android O, until I noticed that the service terminated after a while and did not restart on its own. To make it manually restart, I had to either open the app or restart my device.

Basically, I want to model my TTSService as a *sticky, jobservice* **(basically, it should be restarted by the OS once it ends)**. For this purpose, can I just restart the service in the *onStopJob()* method of the TTSJobScheduledService? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: about the basic service will be removed after progress on the background oreo android. if you want to live service you must initialize one notification with startForeground

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
        return true;
    }
```

The above method call will depend on system resource availability. Also, it is not necessary that jobscheduler will start the job within given deadline which you have mentioned in your jobscheduler.

**eg: builder.setOverrideDeadline(3 * 1000);**

After some time if job scheduler found not in use, the system itself stop the service.

You can also start job inside your **onStopJob()** method but it always depends on your requirement that how frequently you are using it.

As per the latest android background limitation, your changes will work. If you want any kind of user interaction, Go ahead to use **startForegroundService()**.

Please refer blog for more details : https://medium.com/exploring-android/exploring-background-execution-limits-on-android-oreo-ab384762a66c